# How to get all direct child elements of current element via CSS Selectors?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I'd like to get all child elements of some specific element with Selenium. Let's say I have the following HTML:

```
<html>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Test 1</td>
      <td id="123">Test <b>2</b>
        <span>span_text</span>
      </td>
      <td>Test 3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</html>
```

First, I'd like to find the second td element by its id and then I'd like to find all of its child elements (i.e. the b and span elements). Finding the second td element isn't hard:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

page_source = """<table> 
                   <tr>
                        <td>Test 1</td>
                        <td id="123">Test<b>2</b><span>span_text</span></td>
                        <td>Test 3</td>
                   </tr> 
                 </table>
                 """

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.execute_script('document.documentElement.innerHTML=arguments[0]', f"<html>{page_source}</html>")

element = driver.find_element(By.ID, "123")
```

In order to find the child elements, I tried the `td > *` CSS Selector:

```py
for elements in element.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, f"td > *"):
    print(element.tag_name)
```

However, this prints two `td` tags instead of `b` and `span`. I also tried the `. > *` CSS Selector instead, which seems to be invalid. How I can select all (direct) child elements of an WebElement in Selenium by CSS Selectors?

Note: I want to use the `element.find_elements()` method, i.e. I want selenium to only search within the already found element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there. Your code is perfect. You just need to keep a track that within `for` statement in each iteration the decendants are referred as *`elements`*. So you have to invoke:

```
print(elements.tag_name) # instead of element, it should be elements
```

Here is the complete program:

```
page_source = """<table> 
           <tr>
            <td>Test 1</td>
            <td id="123">Test<b>2</b><span>span_text</span></td>
            <td>Test 3</td>
           </tr> 
         </table>
         """

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
driver.execute_script('document.documentElement.innerHTML=arguments[0]', f"<html>{page_source}</html>")
element = driver.find_element(By.ID, "123")
for elements in element.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, f"td > *"):
    print(elements.tag_name)
```

Output:

```
b
span
```

Comment: Thanks. May I also ask how I could get all siblings from the above td element with id=123? Unfortunately the CSS Selector `td ~ *` doesn't work. In the above example the only sibling would be the last td element with text="Test 3".

Comment: `~` is used to identify element preceeded by some other element. As an example, `p ~ ul` Selects every `<ul>` element that is preceded by a `<p>` element. So it should return only a single element.

Answer (score 1):

There's a bug in your code :)

```
for elements in element.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, f"td > *"):
    print(element.tag_name)
                ^ elements
```

This should be `elements.tag_name` (plural of element) to use the loop variable, `elements`. Your variable on the previous line is `element` so you were printing the TD from the previous line twice.

Having said that, you can do this in a single step and simplify your code and save a little time

```
for element in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[id='123'] > *"):
    print(element.tag_name)
```